# Finding the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Given the matrix $A∈M_3(Z_9)$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 6 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The determinant is:

$\det(A)=18+18-24=3$

So the matrix is invertible because the determinant is different from zero.

The transposed matrix is:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 \\
    2 & 3 & 3 \\
    3 & 0 & 6 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The matrix $A'$ is:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 6 & 0 \\
    6 & 6 & 6 \\
    6 & 6 & 8 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

So the inverse matrix is:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    2 & 2 & 2 \\
    2 & 2 & 8/3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Please tell me if my attempt is correct.

Comment: How do you *define* $3^{-1}$ in $\Bbb Z_9$?

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot $\mathbb Z_9$. But what is $8/3$ ?

Comment: @GNUSupporter actually I don't know that, in fact I think that $8/3$ is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's eight third. I don't know how to transform it in $Z_9$ to be honest

Comment: $3x=8$ has no solution in $\mathbb Z_9$.

Comment: @Gag You can't because $\;3\;$ isn't invertible modulo $\;9\;$

Comment: @YvesDaoust So what did I do wrong?

Comment: @DonAntonio So what's my error?

Comment: @Gag To assume the matrix is invertible only because its determinant is non-zero. It **must be** that its determinant is a unit in the ring we're working on.

Comment: @DonAntonio I've always thought that a matrix can be invertible if the determinant is non-zero. How can it be wrong??

Comment: @Gag The identity $$\bbox[2px, border: 1px solid red]{\det(A)I_n=AC^T=C^TA}$$ holds for *any* commutative ring (equipped with $+$ and commutative $\times$), where $C$ is the cofactor matrix.  I don't *think* that you can move $\det(A)$ to the RHS by multiplicative inverse since it's *undefined*.

Comment: @Gag Most probably you worked your way through a basic course in linear algebra, where most (or all...) the matrices we work with are defined on **fields**, and on fields it is enough for an element to be non-zero in order to be invertible. Not so on other rings...

Comment: @GNUSupporter I can't see how that comment is going to help the OP, who seems to be struggling with other things...

Comment: @DonAntonio OP wants to calculate an *inverse* of $A$, but I *suspect* that it doesn't exist from the identity, so you can't even calculate a nonexistent object.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the non-existence of the inverse can be proven by row echelon form calculation.  This is a more basic approach.

\begin{align}
& \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \\
&\sim \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -6 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] (R_2 \leftarrow R_2 - 2R_1) \\
&\sim \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] (R_2 \leftarrow -R_2) \\
&\sim \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -12 & -6 & 3 & 1
\end{array}\right] (R_3 \leftarrow R_3 - 3R_2) \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align}

One is tempted to divide the last row by $6$, but since we are in $\Bbb Z_9$, this is *not* permitted.  In fact, the row operations above show that $A$ has *no* inverse in $M_3(\Bbb Z_9)$: If we omit the fourth and the fifth column of of the above augmented matrices, we are actually finding a solution to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&3&0\\
0&3&6
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Through the above row echelon form, we deduce that $6x_3 = 1$ in $\Bbb Z_9$, which is absurd.  Therefore, $A$ is *noninvertible* in $M_3(\Bbb{Z}_9)$.