# Is a matrix NOT invertible when there are all zeros in a row?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Given the matrix $A∈M_3(Z_9)$

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 6 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

By multiplying the third row by $3$ we have:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

So the matrix is not invertible because there are all zeros in a row, am I right?

Comment: You can't multiply by $3$ because it is not invertible.

Comment: @KennyLau How am I supposed to find if it is invertible then?

Comment: @Gag What is the determinant?

Comment: This is exactly your old question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612695/finding-the-inverse-of-a-matrix).Please do not repost old questions.

Comment: The bottom row is divisible by $3$, which is a zero-divisor in $\Bbb Z_9$.

Answer (score 0):

Allowed operations for matrix in ring $R$:

- Swap two rows
- Subtract $a$ times any row from any other row where $a \in R$
- Multiply any row by $b$ where $b \in R^*$

---

Let $A \in M_3(\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z)$ be given by:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Subtract twice the first row from the second row:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 8 & 3 \\ 0 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Negate the second row:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 6 \\ 0 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Subtract twice the second row from the first row:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 6 \\ 0 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Subtract thrice the second row from the third row:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 6 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Subtract the third row from the second row:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Since $6$ is not invertible, $A$ is not invertible.

---

Or you could have calculated its determinant as suggested in the comments, which is $3$, which is not invertible.

Comment: Please note that the question has been asked three times before by this person:)

Comment: @DietrichBurde what a person... downvoted question.

Comment: What does it mean that $3$ is not invertible?

Comment: @Gag I shall not answer your further questions.

Comment: @KennyLau Why? I have an exam, please help me.

Comment: @Gag I am not responsible for helping you pass your exam.

Comment: @KennyLau Can you at least answer that question please?